# How to get form when it is which is not visible?

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I want to get form which is open but hidden. I have tried by this. I get the form but in this case form show and hide within fraction of second. If I skip `mfrm.Show()`, I don't get MailSynchronize form in `Application.OpenForms`.

```
MailSynchronize mfrm = new MailSynchronize();
mfrm.Show();
mfrm.Hide();
```

I get form by following method.

```
foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)    //it will return all the open forms
{
     if (f.Name == "MailSynchronize")
     {
          mfrm = (MailSynchronize)f;
          break;
     }
}
```

Can anybody please suggest me how to get open form which is hidden by default and I can get in `Application.OpenForms`?

Comment: If you only require ONE instance of that form, you might want to consider using a `Singleton`.

Comment: Not worth to write an answer: save instance of `mfrm`, make it a field accessible via property and use that property instead of enumerating `Application.OpenForms`.

Answer (score 2):

**If I Hide a form, does it exist in Application.OpenForms?**

No, unfortunately if you `Hide` a form, it will not be present in `Application.OpenForms`

**So how can I open an invisible Form? Also I want it to exists in Application.OpenForms.**

If you want to open an invisible Form, and you want it want it to exists in Application.OpenForms, you can use this code instead of simply `Show()`:

```
var f = new MailSynchronize();
f.Opacity = 0; 
f.ShowInTaskbar = false;
f.Show();
```

**How to find that form again?**

To get the open instance of form you can use `Application.OfType<MailSynchronize>()`

```
var f= Application.OpenForms.OfType<MailSynchronize>()
                  .FirstOrDefault();
```

**When I found it, How to show it again?**

```
f.Opacity = 1;
f.ShowInTaskbar = true;
f.Show();
```

**How to hide it again?**

You should not call `Hide()` to hide the form because it makes the form to get out of `Application.OpenForms`, instead you should use this way:

```
f.Opacity = 0; 
f.ShowInTaskbar = false;
```

**Is there another way?**

Yes, for example you can create an static property in a class, for example in `Program.cs` this way:

```
public static MailSynchronize MailSynchronizeInstance { get; set; }
```

and the first time you want to open your form, you can assign the instance to this property, and then you can use it using Program.MailSynchronizeInstance to show or hide and you don't need to look in `Application.OpenForms` or perform a workaround.

Also you can make this property in a singletone way.

Comment: I doesn't get the form. I get if I use "MailSynchronize mfrm = new MailSynchronize(); mfrm.Show(); mfrm.Hide();. Please suggest me how to open form.

Comment: @NJBhanushali Check the updates and descriptions. I think the answer contains what you need.

Comment: Aghaie it is working fine for first time. I don't know why but I am not getting the form in Application.OpenForms second time. Anyhow its working fine in other way. Please check the answer.

Comment: @NJBhanushali The thing that may cause such problem is calling `Hide()`

Comment: @NJBhanushali You should make the form invisible the way that described in answer. "How to hide it again?"

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

This should work for your specific case now:

```
this.Opacity = 0;
this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
```

When you add these 2 codelines in your MailSynchronize constructor the form will start minimized but will not show in your taskbar, which is essentially the effect you were looking for. Also the form will now popup in your Application.OpenForms Collection.

Comment: I have tried but same result as above. First it shows the form and then it hide the form. In this case, user can easily identify that form is open and then hidden.

Comment: I have edited my answer, the second answer should be able to help you more now.

Comment: Can you please tell me how and where I should use this override method?

Comment: You take this override method and put it in your MailSynchronize form. And if you now call the MailSynchronize form it should be hidden.

Comment: It stop to show and hide the form. But I am not getting the form in Application.OpenForms.

Comment: If I remove override method. I get the form in Application.OpenForms if I use "mfrm.Show(); mfrm.Visible = false();". But in this case, it shows form first time.

Comment: Well, I am sorry but I didn't describe full scenario. I have button in other form. That button make this form visible. MailSynchronize form contain Resize event which calculate height on the base of number of mail account. I can't Minimize the form. Let me know if any other way is there rather minimizing. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: Ok... You can instead of minimize, set the opacity of the MailSynchronize form on 0.

Comment: Yeah. it's working fine. I am getting form in Application.OpenForms first time. But I am not getting form in Application.OpenForms once I set it's opacity 0 to 100. May be I need to do verify the event again. I will let you know the result. Thank you.

Comment: Setting the opacity back to 1 should be enough, if you like the answer please give it an accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you buddy. It is working fine for first time. I don't know why but I am not getting the form in Application.OpenForms second time. Anyhow its working fine in other way. Please check the answer and thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

When form initiallize.

```
MailSynchronize mfrm = new MailSynchronize();
mfrm.Opacity = 0;
mfrm.Show();
mfrm.Hide();
```

How to find that form again?

```
foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)    //it will return all the open forms
{
     if (f.Name == "MailSynchronize")
     {
          mfrm = (MailSynchronize)f;
          break;
     }
}
```

When I found it, How to show it again?

```
mfrm.Opacity = 1;
mfrm.Show();
```

Hide again by Button.

```
mfrm.Hide();    //It will not show form in Application.OpenForms if I hide again by mfrm.Opacity = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

use f.Visible (return type is bool)

if it returns false, it means form is hidden. If it returns true then form is visible.