# Get the owner Form of a NotifyIcon?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, forms, winforms

In C# or Vb.Net, using managed or unmanaged code, how I could retrieve the owner `Form` of a `NotifyIcon`?

I've checked the base types of `NotifyIcon` Class and also the `ComponentConverter` trying to find out a possible type-casting to obtain the Form, but I was not able to.

I also seen the `NotifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip.FindForm()` function, but for any reason when I assign a contextmenustrip the `FindForm()` function always returns a null-reference exception, and anyways even if it could work will not be a safe approach because I could have a notifyicon without a contextmenu.

My intention is to pass a `NotifyIcon` as an argument to some methods that will perform common tasks to save me time and reduct code.

Pseudo example:

```
Public Shared Sub MinimizeToSystray(ByVal ntfy As NotifyIcon)

    If (ntfy Is Nothing) Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException(paramName:="ntfy")

    ElseIf (ntfy.Icon Is Nothing) Then
        Throw New ArgumentException(message:="The NotifyIcon doesn't have an icon.",
                                    paramName:="ntfy")

    Else
        Dim f As Form = ntfy.GetOwnerForm()
        f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
        f.Hide()

        ntfy.Visible = True

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: There is no such thing "owner Form of a NotifyIcon". If you want to associate additional data with `NotifyIcon`, as usual `Tag` property is free to use.

Comment: While you can set the `Tag` property as offered by @IvanStoev in code, I posted a design-time supported solution that you can use to set the `Tag` at design-time if you are a designer fan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FindForm() method can only find the form for controls.  The kind that derive from Control and are embedded in a form through its Parent property.  But NotifyIcon is not a control, it is Component.  A Component only has a Site property, its value is only defined at design time.

There is a casual relationship between a component and the form, Winforms promises to automatically dispose any components that have a constructor overload that takes an IContainer argument.  Not all them do, OpenFormDialog and BackgroundWorker for example don't, NotifyIcon does. They omit the constructor when they don't need disposal.

Which makes it *technically* possible to find the form back.  You'd need to iterate Application.OpenForms().  And use reflection to iterate their private `components` collection.  Do note that this can only work when the form was actually opened, its Show() method must have been called.

That's a solution that scores -100 points, it is both ugly and error prone.  The simple and always-correct solution is to just add an extra argument to the method to allow passing the "owner" form.  With the assumption that, since the caller needs to know the NotifyIcon instance, it also should know the form.  Typically `Me`.

Comment: Thankyou as always, its great to receive an answer from you. I'll start trying to match the Form.Components member via Reflection, and if not possible by my own, proceed by adding an additional parameter that takes the Form as you've suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Component doesn't have a `FindForm` method like controls and if you need such property you should customize the component and apply a workaround. Unfortunately `NotifyIcon` is `sealed` and can not be inherited.

As mentioned by [Ivan Stoev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33939858/get-the-owner-form-of-a-notifyicon#comment55641825_33939858) in comments, you can use `Tag` property to store a reference to the container form.

But If you are looking for a designer based solution that works without writing such initialization codes to set the `Tag`, as a good option, you can create an [extender component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6c1xa43.aspx) that adds a property `ParentForm` to your `NotifyIcon` component and set the property at design-time, then you can simply use it at run-time and when setting the `ParentForm` property at design-time you can set `Tag` property in component code, and then use it at run-time.

**And here is the usage:**

Add a the `ComponentExtender` (see the code at the end of post) to your project, then build the project. Then:

1. Add the `ComponentExtender` from toolbox to your form
2. Set the `ParentForm on componentExtender1` property of your `notifyIcon1` at designer using property grid:

[image]

Use this code to find the parent form of your notify icon:

```
var parent = this.notifyIcon1.Tag as Form`
```

**Code**

Here is an implementation that I used and works properly:

```
[ProvideProperty("ParentForm", typeof(NotifyIcon))]
public class ComponentExtender 
    : System.ComponentModel.Component, System.ComponentModel.IExtenderProvider
{
    private Hashtable components;
    public ComponentExtender() : base() { components = new Hashtable(); }

    public bool CanExtend(object extendee)
    {
        if (extendee is Component)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public Form GetParentForm(NotifyIcon extendee)
    {
        return components[extendee] as Form;
    }

    public void SetParentForm(NotifyIcon extendee, Form value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            components.Remove(extendee);
            component.Tag = null;
        }
        else
        {
            components[extendee] = value;
            component.Tag = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your time, it is a good solution, however, it implies design-time interaction which is what I wanted to avoid. I'm looking for a more abstract/automated solution for example using Reflection. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome and thank you for your feedback :) as I said this solution is good for designer fans ;)

Comment: By the way, when using `Application.OpenForms` be careful because if you hide a form, it no longer exists in the collection. You may find [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33101656/3110834) helpful if you are going to hide forms and bring them up using notify icon.